# Navigate different panels for different hyperlinks

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink, webforms

I have two hyperlinks:

1. edit
2. delete

in gridview. I have another aspx page with two panels:

1. UpdatePanel
2. DeletePanel

When I click the edit button in grid view it has to fire update panel in another aspx page, while delete button in grid view has to fire delete panel in another aspx page.

How can I do this?

Comment: In grid view right side there is a arrow mark click that, there u will get edit column, select that, . In selected field list click edit and below u will get a template field select that .

Comment: And again click that grid view arrow and select edit template, u can see that edit button, double click it , and write your function to redirect to update panel

Comment: how can write function,suppose for  update panel in the page named PROJECT

Comment: let me explain u below

Comment: Thanx a lot..it will b very helpfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is your Grid view ,
**Step 1:** Click Edit Columns first

[image]

**step 2:** Here in this page select each buttons in Selected field and select Convert this field to Template Field. and click OK

[image]

**Step3:** Here Click Edit Template

[image]

**step4:** There u can see GridView- Column[0] whcih is of edit button, double click that button , a method will be generated , inside that write Response.Redirect("~/PROJECT.aspx"); , if ur page name is PROJECT.

[image]

Comment: thanx a lot...also i hve to redirect to UpdatePanel of Project.aspx page without taking values.it have to fire that udate panel alone.

Comment: in page load of project.aspx call updatepanel inside, if(!IsPostBack){// call update panel}